# Calculate. $\int_{\alpha}z^2 \log(\frac{z+1}{z-1})\,dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need help with this excercise.

Calculate.

$$\int_{\alpha}z^2 \log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz$$

for $\alpha$ is $|z|=2$.

---

$\log( z) = \log(|z|) + i\arg (z) + 2k\pi i; k \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: -2 -_-  i just need tips

Answer (score 5):

If we cut the plane from $z=-1$ to $z=1$, then $z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$ is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus [-1,1]$.

Since $|z|=2$ contain all of the singularities of $z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$ with the chosen branch cut, we have for all $R>2$

$$\begin{align}
\oint_{|z|=2}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz&=\oint_{|z|=R}z^2\log\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)\,dz\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} R^2e^{i2\phi}\left(\log\left(1+\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}\right)-\log\left(1-\frac{1}{Re^{i\phi}}\right)\right)\,iRe^{i\phi}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi} iR^3e^{i3\phi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1-(-1)^{n}}{nR^ne^{in\phi}}\,d\phi\\\\
&=i4\pi /3
\end{align}$$

since $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{im\phi}\,d\phi=0$ for $m\ne 0$ and $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{im\phi}\,d\phi=2\pi$ for $m=0$.

Comment: Nice and simple. (+1)

Comment: @did Thank you Didier.  Much appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\oint_{z = 2}z^{2}\ln\pars{z + 1 \over z - 1}\,\dd z &
\,\,\,\stackrel{z\ \mapsto\ 1/z}{=}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\oint_{z = 1/2}\ln\pars{1 + z \over 1 - z}\,{\dd z \over z^{4}}}
^{\substack{The\ integrand\ has\ an\ order\\[0.5mm]
            3\ pole\ inside\ the\ contour.}}
=
2\pi\ic\,{1 \over 2!}\,\lim_{z \to 0}\totald[2]{}{z}
\bracks{{1 \over z}\ln\pars{1 + z \over 1 - z}}
\\[5mm] & =
\pi\ic\,\lim_{z \to 0}\totald[2]{}{z}\pars{2 + {2 \over 3}\,z^{2}} =
\pi\ic \times {4 \over 3} = \bbx{{4 \over 3}\,\pi\ic}
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Felix, why do u do,, $z -> 1/z$ ? theorem?

Comment: @Mathyobani By doing so, he obtains an equivalent integral whose integrand is analytic on a *ball* containing $z=1/2$, and Cauchy's formula becomes available. You cannot use Cauchy in $\mathbb C\smallsetminus [-1,1]$ and the ball $B(0,2)$.

Comment: mm yes, but why is equivalent integral,  why $1/z^4$

Comment: im sorry but i am starting in complex integral.. thanks Felix

Comment: Could you recommend a book that addresses these changes of integral?

Comment: @Mathyobani It's equivalent to the change of variables $z = 1/w \implies \,\mathrm{d}z = -\,\mathrm{d}w/w^{2}$ and the 'prefactor' $z^{2}$ becomes $1/w^{2}$ and $\left(1/w^2\right)\left(1/w^2\right) = 1/w^{4}$. The minus sign makes the rotation clockwise such that we multiply the integral by $-1$ to restore the counterclockwise rotation. Similarly, $\ln\left(z + 1 \over z - 1\right) = \ln\left(1/w + 1 \over 1/w - 1\right) = \ln\left(1 + w \over 1 - w\right)$. Then, rename $w$ as $z$ ( it's mute ). In order to be 'economic',  we can use the same letter $z$ with the 'cheap' notation $z \to 1/z$.

Comment: @Mathyobani Any textbook makes those changes of variable. Specially, in the topic of Conformal Transformations.

Comment: @Mathyobani [See this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map).

Comment: mm thanks, :)  just... when u change $z=1/z$ why the roration change??

Comment: @Mathyobani $z = \exp\left(\mathrm{i}\theta\right) \implies w = 1/z = \exp\left(-\mathrm{i}\theta\right)$.